# weird line-break behaviour in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a really weird problem with IE. 
The text breaks (completely unnecessary) in to more lines even though there is plenty room for it. This only happens sometimes when reload page with ctr + 5. If I edit anything (doesnt matter what) in devtools it looks normal again..

[This is how it should look (2 lines)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6huRZ.png)

[and this is how it looks when its wrong (3 lines)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMqLg.png)

```css
.tag {
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 4.95216px;
  padding-bottom: 4.95216px;
  background-color: #0077c0;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #0077c0;
  border-radius: 33px;
}

.tagline {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: webfont-Frutiger, sans-serif;
  word-break: break-word;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 8.516px;
  padding-left: 8.516px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag">
  <span class="tagline">la lalalalala, lalalala lala lalalalal lalalalalalalalalalal lalala lalal lala lalalalalaa lala lalala lalal lalaal lala lala lal lalalalalalala lalala.
    </span>
</div>
```

In chrome it always looks at it sholud.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: would like to add that this only happens in our testserver..not in my devserver..dont know if this has anything to do with it..

Comment: For us to be able to help with an issue, the issue need to be reproduced with your posted code sample, and this one doesn't as it looks the same in both Chrome and IE.

Comment: Can you please inform us, which version of the IE has this issue? If this issue can only occurred with 1 specific machine than it is possible that there is something wrong with that IE application. You can try to reset the IE and again try to make a test for the issue. Let us know about your testing result, We will try to provide further suggestions. If needed.